# Symfony UniqueEntity Exception

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

OK, I know this has been asked a million times, but here goes.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001753/why-is-my-symfony2-uniqueentity-constraint-not-working-at-all), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877638/uniqueentity-constraint), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547001/symfony2-doctrine-uniqueentity-handle-exception) as well as [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html), but still can't figure out what my issue is. Whenever I try and add a user with a duplicate username / email, I get an exception instead of the expected form validation error. I have a SystemUser entity that is linked via joined inheritance mapping to various other user types. In the SystemUser class, I have this...

```
/**
 * SystemUser
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="systemuser")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyBundle\MainBundle\Entity\Repository\SystemUserRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="integer")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"0" = "SystemUser", "1" = "SchoolAdmin", "2" = "Teacher", "3" = "Student", "4" = "Guardian", "5" = "SystemAdmin"})
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="This email address is already used in the system", groups={"registration"})
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"username"}, message="This cellphone number is already used in the system", groups={"registration"})
 */
```

On the fields themselves (email, username) I also have `unique=true`. I tried without it, same exception. I also tried without the `groups={"registration"}` flag, I'm not sure whether the 'registration' group has to be specified and declared somewhere though (I did check the docs but couldn't find anything). In fact, I have no clue what the validation group is actually good for in this instance, but I tried it nonetheless.

Failing there, I moved to trying validation.yml...

```
MyBundle\MainBundle\Entity\SystemUser:
    constraints:
        - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity: email
        - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity: username
    properties:
        email:
            - Email: { groups: [registration] }
        password:
            - NotBlank: { groups: [registration] }
            - Length: { min: 7, groups: [registration] }
        cellphone:
            - NotBlank: { groups: [registration] }
```

Still, obviously, no result. Failing there, I went on to the form class's `setDefaultOptions()` method.

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'MyBundle\MainBundle\Entity\SystemUser',
            'validation_groups' => array('registration'),
            'cascade_validation' => true,
            'constraints' => array(
                new UniqueEntity(array(
                    'fields' => array('email')
                )),
                new UniqueEntity(array(
                    'fields' => array('username')
                ))
            )
        ));
    }
```

Also, without any luck. Currently I have all 3 of these active together, but still nothing. I tried them all separately, but again, no luck.

If anybody could point out what's going on here, I would greatly appreciate it. Been struggling with this for about 6 hours now.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your complete Entity and FormType classes (or at least the most stripped down version that still fails) so we can test your exact implementation?

Answer (score -1):

You should try to replace :

#### Annotation

```
/**
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="This email address is already used in the system", groups={"registration"})
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"username"}, message="This cellphone number is already used in the system", groups={"registration"})
 */
```

by this :

```
/**
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email", "username"}, message="A user with those email and username already exists", groups={"registration"})
 */
```

#### Yaml

```
constraints:
    - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity: email
    - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity: username
```

by this :

```
constraints:
    - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity:
        - email
        - username
```

#### PHP (Type class)

```
'constraints' => array(
    new UniqueEntity(array(
        'fields' => array('email')
    )),
    new UniqueEntity(array(
        'fields' => array('username')
    ))
)
```

by this :

```
'constraints' => array(
    new UniqueEntity(array(
        'fields' => array('email', 'username')
    ))
)
```

Comment: Won't that be saying "hey, MySQL, check if there's a record where the email AND the username is equal to this email AND username"? I need to specify that email must be unique, as well as username. Not a combination of the two. Or am I not correct here?

Comment: Ok. Sorry I misunderstood the question. Will think about another solution... Remove all references to the validation group `registration` doesn't make it work?

Comment: Nope, tried both with and without the registration group, but as I said, I'm not sure whether I should have explicitly created it somehow? Documentation doesn't turn anything up.

Comment: Removing `'validation_groups' => array('registration')` form your `setDefaultOptions()` function should work. I advise you to chose only one of the 3 methods described in your question as we can focus on it. Using annotations, remove also `groups={"registration"}`.